# how do you set nil to codable enum when unexpected value in swift iOS

Tags: swift, enums, codable

I'm using `Codable` for my WebRequest response which is returning some predefined string or number. So, I'm using Enums for those. But when some unexpected value arrive to Response at that my Codable fails to decode.

Here some code for better understanding.

```
class WebUser: Codable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: WebUser, rhs: WebUser) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    ...
    var mobileNumberPrivacy: CommonPrivacyOption?
    var emailPrivacy: CommonPrivacyOption?
    var dobPrivacy: CommonPrivacyOption?
    ...
}

enum CommonPrivacyOption: Int, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case privacyOnlyMe = 1, privacyPublic, privacyFriends, privacyFriendsOfFriends

    //Does not help this optional init function
    /*init?(rawValue: Int) {
        switch rawValue {
            case 1: self = .privacyOnlyMe
            case 2: self = .privacyPublic
            case 3: self = .privacyFriends
            case 4: self = .privacyFriendsOfFriends
            default: return nil
        }
    }*/

}
```

but sometimes from WebServer I'm getting, 0 for `dobPrivacy` at that time I'm getting `DecodingError.dataCorrupted` exception with context `Cannot initialize CommonPrivacyOption from invalid Int value 0`

As I expect to dobPrivacy nil when I get other values then 1/2/3/4.

**EDIT:**

```
let dict1 = [
    "id": 2,
    "mobileNumberPrivacy": 3,
    "emailPrivacy": 4,
    "dobPrivacy": 0 // Works perfectly with 1
]
do {
    let data1 = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict1, options: .prettyPrinted)
    let user1 = try JSONDecoder().decode(WebUser.self, from: data1)
    print("User1 created")
}
catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let context) {
    print(context.codingPath)
    print(context.debugDescription)
}
catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

I'm using this same Codable WebUser object for Profile detail, search users and many more.
so may be some times one more key will not present in WebRequest's response.

Comment: "Does not help this optional init function" what happens?

Comment: using or not using same result. throwing Decodable error

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]

Comment: @Alexander Removed protocol declaration and some other methods

Comment: This is still not code that we can run. Fix that.

Answer (score 11):

I recommend writing a property wrapper that handles this problem for you.

Specifically, let's write a property wrapper named `NilOnDecodingError` that turns any `DecodingError` into `nil`.

Here's the declaration of `NilOnDecodingError`:

```
@propertyWrapper
public struct NilOnDecodingError<Wrapped> {
    public init(wrappedValue: Wrapped?) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }

    public var wrappedValue: Wrapped?
}
```

We've defined it to wrap any type, storing an `Optional`.

Now we can conform it to `Decodable` when the `Wrapped` type is `Decodable`:

```
extension NilOnDecodingError: Decodable where Wrapped: Decodable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            wrappedValue = .some(try container.decode(Wrapped.self))
        } catch is DecodingError {
            wrappedValue = nil
        }
    }
}
```

We probably also want it to be `Encodable` when the `Wrapped` type is `Encodable`:

```
extension NilOnDecodingError: Encodable where Wrapped: Encodable {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let value = wrappedValue {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else {
            try container.encodeNil()
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can wrap the appropriate fields of `WebUser`:

```
class WebUser: Codable {
    let id: String

    @NilOnDecodingError
    var mobileNumberPrivacy: CommonPrivacyOption?

    @NilOnDecodingError
    var emailPrivacy: CommonPrivacyOption?

    @NilOnDecodingError
    var dobPrivacy: CommonPrivacyOption?
}
```

For testing, we'll want to print the fields of the decoded user:

```
extension WebUser: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return """
        WebUser(
            id: \(id),
            mobileNumberPrivacy: \(mobileNumberPrivacy.map { "\($0)" } ?? "nil"),
            emailPrivacy: \(emailPrivacy.map { "\($0)" } ?? "nil")),
            dobPrivacy: \(dobPrivacy.map { "\($0)" } ?? "nil")))
        """
    }
}
```

Now we can try it out:

```
let json = """
{
    "id": "mrugesh",
    "mobileNumberPrivacy": 1,
    "emailPrivacy": 2,
    "dobPrivacy": 1000
}
"""

let user = try! JSONDecoder().decode(WebUser.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
print(user)
```

Output:

```
WebUser(
    id: mrugesh,
    mobileNumberPrivacy: privacyOnlyMe,
    emailPrivacy: privacyPublic),
    dobPrivacy: nil))
```

Comment: Fan of your solution. But as I'm using same Model class for one or more WebRequest's so some times one more key (property) will not be present in response, so at that time this solution is throwing error like below.

`could not find key CodingKeys(stringValue: "mobile_number_privacy", intValue: nil) in JSON: No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "mobile_number_privacy", intValue: nil) ("mobile_number_privacy").`

Comment: I have the same problem as @MrugeshTank. This breaks when the field doesn't exist in the response at all. I was hoping it would still be nil in this case, but it still throws an error for reasons I don't understand.

Comment: I figured it out. If you add this it will work when the value field is missing from the JSON:

`public extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    func decode<T>(_ type: NilOnDecodingError<T>.Type, forKey key: Self.Key) throws -> NilOnDecodingError<T>
    where T: Decodable {
        try decodeIfPresent(type, forKey: key) ?? NilOnDecodingError(wrappedValue: nil)
    }
}
`

Comment: That looks like a clever solution (but I haven’t tried it). Feel free to edit it into my answer if you like.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom `Decodable` initializer inside `WebUser`:

```swift
class WebUser: Codable {
    var dobPrivacy: CommonPrivacyOption?
    // Rest of your properties here.

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dobPrivacy
        // Add a case for each property you want to decode here.
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        // Use optional try to decode your enum so that when the
        // decode fails because of wrong Int value, it will assign nil.
        dobPrivacy = try? container.decode(CommonPrivacyOption.self, forKey: .dobPrivacy)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can implement the `Decodable` initializer inside `CommonPrivacyOption` and add an additional `case unknown` like so:

```swift
enum CommonPrivacyOption: Int, Codable {
    case privacyOnlyMe = 1
    case privacyPublic, privacyFriends, privacyFriendsOfFriends
    case unknown

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let value = try container.decode(Int.self)

        // Try to initialize Self from value, if 
        // value is not 1, 2, 3, or 4, initialize Self to 
        // the unknown case.
        self = .init(rawValue: value) ?? .unknown
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternate option will not work for me, cause I'm having CaseIterable confirmation on Enum cause I need selection from user for all options. So, CaseIterable gives me easy way to work with UITableView

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the compiler selects the wrong init for the enum types, instead of `init(rawValue)` it uses `init(from:)` that is the one for decoding (which in a way makes sense)

Here is a solution where we override this behaviour by using a custom `init(from)` in `WebUser` that decodes the raw values and then creates an enum item

```
required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    if let value = try container.decodeIfPresent(CommonPrivacyOption.RawValue.self, forKey: .mobileNumberPrivacy), let mobileNumberPrivacy = CommonPrivacyOption(rawValue: value) {
        self.mobileNumberPrivacy = mobileNumberPrivacy
    }
    if let value = try container.decodeIfPresent(CommonPrivacyOption.RawValue.self, forKey: .emailPrivacy), let emailPrivacy = CommonPrivacyOption(rawValue: value) {
        self.emailPrivacy = emailPrivacy
    }
    if let value = try container.decodeIfPresent(CommonPrivacyOption.RawValue.self, forKey: .dobPrivacy), let dobPrivacy = CommonPrivacyOption(rawValue: value) {
        self.dobPrivacy = dobPrivacy
    }
}
```

Below is a small example

```
extension WebUser: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        "Mobile: \(mobileNumberPrivacy?.rawValue), email: \(emailPrivacy?.rawValue), dob: \(dobPrivacy?.rawValue)"
    }
}

let data = """
{
    "mobileNumberPrivacy": 1,
    "dobPrivacy": 0
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(WebUser.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

> Mobile: Optional(1), email: nil, dob: nil

---

Of course if you can change your mind about 0 being translated to nil then I would suggest you extend the enum to support the 0 value

```
enum CommonPrivacyOption: Int, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case none = 0
    case privacyOnlyMe = 1, privacyPublic, privacyFriends, privacyFriendsOfFriends
}
```

Then it should work out of the box and you don't need to write any custom code.

Comment: Do I need to write if statements for all property in `init(from)` method?
Cause I'm having 85+ properties in class as I'm using common User object for whole app

Comment: Are all properties of this enum type?

Comment: No, Some are Enum Types, Some are nested Class and some are Basic data type (e.g. String, Int)

Comment: Well you only need to write the if statements for the enum properties but you need to handle all properties in the `init(from decoder: Decoder)`. With 85+ properties maybe it is better to support zero as  an enum value instead. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, I can add none propery to Enum but I'm having CaseIterable confirmation on Enum cause I need selection from user for all options. So, CaseIterable gives me easy way to work with UITableView for rows and selection

Comment: You could always filter out the none option before presenting the choices to the user, it could be a computed property in the enum for instance

Answer (score 0):

I liked @alobaili's answer since it's simple and provided a good solution. One thing I wanted to improve is to make it more generic, so that any `Decodable` (and `Codable`) could do it with less code to write.

```swift
extension Decodable where Self: RawRepresentable, RawValue: Decodable {
    
    static func initializedOptionalWith(decoder: Decoder, defaultValue: Self) throws -> Self {
        
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let value = try container.decode(RawValue.self)
        
        return .init(rawValue: value) ?? defaultValue
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    self = try .initializedOptionalWith(decoder: decoder, defaultValue: .unknown)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rob Mayoff for a great answer. I would like to add just one thing - if the property is missing, decoding fails even if the property is optional. To prevent this failure, add the following extension:

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    func decode<T>(_ type: NilOnDecodingError<T>.Type, forKey key: Self.Key) throws -> NilOnDecodingError<T> where T: Decodable {
        try decodeIfPresent(type, forKey: key) ?? NilOnDecodingError<T>(wrappedValue: nil)
    }
}
```